# google docs api only gets the first page of the powerpoint

Tags: rest, google-docs, google-docs-api

so I made an API call to download a power point presentation that is stored in Google Docs...

The url for the api call was

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=somerandomid
```

but then the API call will only return the first page of the powerpoint as a PNG while the powerpoint clearly has multiple pages...

Does anybody know how to get even the other pages for the powerpoint? or better yet...the entire powerpoint presentation?

Comment: I know it's tempting to add the "google-app-engine" tag because it has the word "google" in it, but please don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `&exportformat=ppt` to the end of your api call.

Like below:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=somerandomid&exportformat=ppt
```